# Windows IR device USB List

Tags: python, serial-port, usb, hid

I have IR Frame that acts like mause input in my pc. When I use third part program I can see that devices in usb list:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJgaG.png)

But I want to list that usb device with Python. I used to that code but it didnt work:

```py
import usb
for dev in usb.core.find(find_all=True):
    print(dev)
    print("Device:", dev.filename)
    print("  idVendor: %d (%s)" % (dev.idVendor, hex(dev.idVendor)))
    print("  idProduct: %d (%s)" % (dev.)
```

how can I list that device in my python ?

```py
import usb
for dev in usb.core.find(find_all=True):
    print(dev)
    print("Device:", dev.filename)
    print("  idVendor: %d (%s)" % (dev.idVendor, hex(dev.idVendor)))
    print("  idProduct: %d (%s)" % (dev.)
```